# Как запустить celery на windows?

Tags: python, django, celery

Я создал новый проект django и следовал [документаций celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)
запустил проект через командную строку

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Параллельно запустил celery

```
celery -A shop worker -l INFO
```

Но получил ошибку

> [2021-02-15 17:47:27,918: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect
> to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061] Подключение не
> установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.
> Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

Как правильно запустить celery на localhost?

Comment: Вот [документация](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html?highlight=django) для работы с `Django`.

Comment: @5c0rp Я и следовал этой документаций и получил эту ошибку. Я спецыально указал ссылку на нее.

Comment: моя ссылка явно отличается от вашей

Comment: @5c0rp Опечатался исправил. Я следовал поэтапно ссылке которую вы мне дали и получил эту ошибку когда запустил `celery -A shop worker -l INFO` Что я сделал не так?

Comment: По тексту ошибки очевидно, что вы забыли запустить RabbitMQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно не запущен брокер amqp. Установите https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html и запустите.

Comment: А что нужно вести на http://localhost:15672 для входа?

Comment: входа куда, зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить брокер сообщений, например RabbitMQ или Redis, включить его, затем прописать настройки для Celery, уже потом включить запустить Celery.